# Inputs into R Functions an easier display

Tags: r

Is there a shortcut one could employ to find out all the inputs that go into a R function with  each's respective description? I know you can always `?function.name`, but the help manual opens up either in a web browser or if your using R studio to the right of the screen. Are there any shortcut that let you either see just the inputs or the help description straight into the console?

Comment: if you're working in RStudio, then hitting TAB after you've typed a function name at the console pops up a little help-reminder window. (If you type TAB while you're partway through typing a function name, the pop-up window contains all the possible completions.) It doesn't display the full descriptions of the arguments, but if you type F1 it pops up the help in a separate window.  RStudio is probably the nicest currently available interface for R, unless you're already familiar with a high-powered programming editor/IDE such as vim/emacs/Eclipse etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
args(function_name)
# prints a list of arguments
# not helpful if you're using the function for the first time and have no idea but
# very useful if you just need a quick reminder e.g how the arguments are named
```

BTW when installing R you can choose whether you want help to be displayed as HTML or in a text-based window within R. (But first you have to choose "custom" instead of "typical" [?] install.)

Comment: Not really. Lists out the first few arguments but doesn't describe what the inputs must be.

Comment: thanks Jessica I added two lines to make it more helpful

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting `options(help_type="text")`, perhaps in .Rprofile, except in Rstudio where I don't know a solution. See `?help`.