# How to display to console a custom function summary/introduction?

Tags: r, function, console, summary

This is probably a trivial matter but I just hope to see if there's is a better way to do this.

I wrote a custom function and would like it to display a summary or introduction text to console when I enter it without any parameters, i.e. name-of-custom-function(). Apart from showing me the arguments list (something a simple str() can do), I intended it as a reminder for myself in future.

To resolve this currently, I set the first argument to default NULL and run an 'if' statement to check for NULL. **My question is: Does R have a built-in function/method to set certain user-specified text as the default introduction when writing custom functions, or do I have to handle it myself (e.g. using my 'is.null test') within the function itself?**

A sample code is shown below:

```
myprint <- function(x=NULL, y, ...)
{
  if(is.null(x)==TRUE)
  {
    writeLines( "\nNOTE: This function prints to console what the user keys in.\nmyprint() Function ver 0.1")
  }else
  {
    print(x)
  }
}  ### End of myprint() function ###
```

I couldn't find similar questions/resources online. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924877/inputs-into-r-functions-an-easier-display, but the issues are not the same.

Would appreciate any help given. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this, and "elegant" seems to be a subjective criterion. As such, the question might not be a great fit for asking on SO. However, to contribute one alternative, you could use `missing` instead of the `is.null` paradigm.

Comment: @BenBarnes, I agree that 'elegant' is rather subjective. Have edited my question to: 'Does R have a built-in function/method to set certain user-specified text as the default introduction when writing custom functions, or do I have to handle it myself (e.g. using my 'is.null test') within the function itself?'. Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: If you're looking for a system to document functions for future reference, @hadley has a great reference under http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Documenting-functions.html in which he describes the roxygen system of function/package documentation. Highly recommended.

Comment: hadley's document looks like what I'm looking for. Will take a look. Thanks, @BenBarnes!